# Do defensive bonuses make any difference against Tar Monsters?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

I'm cutting [Sculliusceps](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Sulliuscep) to train woodcutting, and the main issue I'm running into right now is dealing with the damage from [Tar Monsters](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Tar_Monster). The wiki says they deal typeless ranged damage. What does this mean with respect to defensive bonuses? Do their attacks just ignore protection prayers, or do they also ignore defensive bonuses?

Comment: According to the wiki page on [Typeless damage](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Typeless), typeless attacks do ignore prot prayers, but typeless ranged is affected by armour. Typeless style in general (no mage/range/melee) ignores armour (mentioned at the bottom of the wiki page)

Comment: @TerryA so in other words, because they aren't the cabbage wizard, maximizing ranged defense will have some effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some investigation, the wiki seems to suggest that their attacks are technically impacted by ranged defense. However, when you consider the [Lumberjack outfit](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Lumberjack_outfit) takes up 4 slots (and is not very difficult to obtain), the remaining absolutely best in slot ranged defense is +124, with some pretty heavy and expensive gear (granite shield, infernal cape, amulet of fury, barrows gloves, ring of suffering (i)). In my case, the more practical best ranged defense is +99 (granite shield, cape of legends, amulet of fury, barrows gloves). Even with this, they still hit fairly accurately.

A lot of people cutting sculliusceps wear regeneration items instead; hitpoints cape, regen bracelet. Both of these double the regeneration rate, stacking to 4hp per minute (you can also regen at this rate with the rapid heal prayer and a regen bracelet). However, a regen bracelet currently costs 2,903,068 coins, and a hitpoints cape requires 99 hitpoints, so bringing a handful of monkfish, an antidote++, and logging in to the official world (321) to get targeted less often seems like the better way to go.

Comment: I've actually noticed a decent number of 0 hits adding the granite shield. They still hit pretty often, but every now and then it'll be a 0 (vs almost always a hit without it)